# How do I make inexact string comparisons with Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, pattern-matching, match

Given two strings, I want to find all common substrings of a specified length, but allowing one character to be different.

For example, if s1 is `'ATCAGC'`, s2 is `'ATAATCGAC'`, and the specified length is `3`, then I'd want output along these lines:

```
ATC from s1 matches ATA, ATC from s2
TCA from s1 matches TAA, TCG from s2
```

**Questions**

- Can I do so with a simple regex?
- If not, is there module for this in Perl?

Comment: I'm not sure why folks are downvoting this. I just gave you +1 - interesting question!

Comment: @ridgerunner, perhaps because there is no question. Sure, there is an implied question "can someone spoon-feed me the regex please?", but that might also have motivated people to down-vote. Who knows?

Comment: @Mariya, You probably should've asked "How do I make inexact string comparisons?  Can I do so with a simple regex?  If not, is there module for this in Perl?"  You could easily find this with google once you knew the comp.sci. jargon.  Regex aren't great for this, but the transliteration operator `tr///` returns useful information.

Comment: @JeffBurdges thank you very much that's exactly what i wanted to ask as I don't know whether regex works or not

Comment: @Mariya : I've edited your question to reflect the question you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, google result for "perl hamming distance" found a [perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=500235) that mentions [Text::LevenshteinXS](http://search.cpan.org/~jgoldberg/Text-LevenshteinXS-0.03/LevenshteinXS.pm), various typical implementations, and a cute xor trick :

```
sub hd{ length( $_[ 0 ] ) - ( ( $_[ 0 ] ^ $_[ 1 ] ) =~ tr[\0][\0] ) }
```

You should skim wikipedia article on [String metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) if Levenshtein distance or Hamming distance aren't familiar.